# How to fill scope variable via Ajax get inside the controller?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angularjs, controller

In my current code I am using a dummy way to get the data. Its like

```
var controlMeetings = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./Info.xml",
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (dataSource) {           

            controlMeetings = PureJson(dataSource);         
        }
});

function MeetingsCtrl( $scope, $compile ) {

  $scope.meetings = controlMeetings;  
  $('#div1').html(
       $compile(
         '<ul><li ng-repeat="meeting in meetings"><a>{{meeting.count}}</a> <ul><li ng-repeat="child in meeting.children">{{child.meet}}</li></ul></li></ul>'
       )($scope)
     );
  $('#div1').prepend('<div class="mHeader">Race cources</div>');


}
```

Its obviously not good (yes I am ashamed from this code), but its working atm. The issue is how to acutally populate the $cope.meetings variable inside the controller and avoid usage of the global variable?

Comment: I think you could do with a grounding in the angular way, follow the tutorials on - http://egghead.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to re-write your example using AngularJS methods.

Controller:

```
function MeetingsCtrl ($scope) {

  $http.get('./Info.xml').success(function (data) {
      $scope.meetings = data;
    });

}
```

View file:

```
<div id="div1">
  <div class="mHeader">Race cources</div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="meeting in meetings">
      <a>{{meeting.count}}</a>
        <ul><li ng-repeat="child in meeting.children">{{child.meet}}</li></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I got "Error: $http is not defined" and after i added function MeetingsCtrl( $scope, $compile, $http ) {
 

    $http.get('./Info.xml').success(function (data) {
        $scope.meetings = data;
    });  then i start getting long running script exception  in jquery 1.9.1

Comment: I forgot to inject `$http`, my bad! `$compile` is not required, though! If you use jQuery's `.html()` to add HTML to the webpage, you are doing it not right, use seperate partial view files! I'm not sure how your `Info.xml` file looks like (I used static data just to show how that works), but see this: http://jsfiddle.net/m23kX/

Comment: But my idea is to reuse the controller in another pages and everytime to inject the html manually. Should i everytime type directly the html ?